# Как сократить код для каждого элемента меню?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

У меня есть меню сайта, сайт состоит из блоков, когда я нахожусь на каком то блоке в меню должен изменяться цвет текста.

Вот это кусок кода будет для каждого элемента меню (я прописал только для одного). Возможно ли сократить этот код?

```
<div class="header-menu">
  <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="what-we-do" href="#whatWeDo">
      <div class="header-menu__text">Чем мы занимаемся?</div>
  </a>
  <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="work-process" href="#workProcess">
    <div class="header-menu__text">Процесс работы</div>
  </a>
  <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="why-us" href="#whyUs">
    <div class="header-menu__text">Почему именно мы?</div>
  </a>
  <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="prices" href="#Prices" id="Pricess">
    <div class="header-menu__text">Прайс</div>
  </a>
  <a class="header-menu__link header-menu__link_order" data-menuanchor="order" href="#Order">
    <div class="header-menu__text">Сделать заказ</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    //Делаю это при каждом скролле
    if(document.location.hash == '#Prices'){
      //Если нахожусь в .../#Prices //Меняю цвет
      document.getElementById('Pricess').style.color = '#f3a7f6';
    } else {
      //Если не в /#Price меняю опять на белый
      document.getElementById('Pricess').style.color = '#fff';
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочтите описание метки [инспекция кода] и дополните вопрос.

Comment: Спс за дополнение! *P.S. Минус не мой.*

Comment: Приведите пример 2-го элемента меню (не понятна закономерность ваших повторений)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Первый элемент: <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="what-we-do" href="#whatWeDo">
      <div class="header-menu__text">Чем мы занимаемся?</div>
  </a> Второй: <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="work-process" href="#workProcess">
    <div class="header-menu__text">Процесс работы</div>
  </a> и т.д

Comment: составьте его скриптом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рядом ответ корректный, однако так намного короче, да и разметку видно:

```js
let menu = [
  ["what-we-do", 'whatWeDo', 'Чем мы занимаемся?'],
  ['work-process', 'workProcess', 'Процесс работы'],
  ['why-us', 'whyUs', 'Почему именно мы?'],
  ['prices', 'Prices', 'Прайс'],
  ['order', 'Order', 'Сделать заказ']
];

headerMenu.innerHTML = menu.map(el => `
  <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="${el[0]}" href="#${el[1]}">
      <div class="header-menu__text">${el[2]}</div>
  </a>
`).join('')
```

```html
<div id="headerMenu" class="header-menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вышло примерно так, таки же образом можно и див создавать и элементы внутри него стразу.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <script>
        const divs = {
            'header-menu': [
                ["what-we-do", '#whatWeDo', 'Чем мы занимаемся?'],
                ['work-process', '#workProcess', 'Процесс работы'],
                ['why-us', '#whyUs', 'Почему именно мы?'],
                ['prices', '#Prices', 'Прайс'],
                ['order', '#Order', 'Сделать заказ']
            ]
        }

        const defclass = 'header-menu__link';
        const textClass = 'header-menu__text';

        for (const [divClass, elements] of Object.entries(divs)) {
            const newDiv = document.createElement('div')
            newDiv.setAttribute('class', divClass)

            for (const el of elements) {
                const newELenement = document.createElement('a')
                newELenement.setAttribute('class', defclass);
                newELenement.setAttribute('data-menuancho', el[0]);
                newELenement.setAttribute('href', el[1]);

                const textDiv = document.createElement('div')
                textDiv.setAttribute('class', textClass)

                textDiv.textContent = el[2]

                newELenement.appendChild(textDiv)
                newDiv.appendChild(newELenement)
            }
            document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: а я бы через innerHTML сделал =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну, я не фронтэндер, да и так вообще можно создать объект со всеми дивами которые нужны, ключ - название дива, значение объект с пропами elements, attributes, которые являются массивами объектов, где ключ - название атрибута, а значение - значение и вообще всю хтмл генерить за примерно такой же кусок кода.